# HTML Form data > PHP > MySQL UTF encoding (cyrillics)

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

Problem: Cyrillic, UTF-8 encoded string, for example, "Михаил", specified in an HTML form, saved by PHP into MYSQL turns to unreadable krakozyabras like "РњРёС…Р°Р№Р»РѕРІРёС‡".

This is now a new problem, but I have found no solution so far... Please help if someone encountered this before.

HTML page is UTF-8 encoded and has properly set META; saving PHP script is UTF-8 encoded (with, or without BOM - doesn't matter). MySL table has DEFAULT ENCODING utf-8:

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_deposit_request` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Any input welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always call

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');`
```

function (or a similar function from the API you are using) right after connecting to database

if there is no such function, run

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

SQL query in the same place

Comment: Perfectly helped! Any ideas why it didn't work before? Database global settings? It worked fine on another application/db server without calling this function. Thanks!

Comment: You don't actually need to have the same charset in your database and HTML page - mysql can recode the data on the fly. that's why you have to specify what encoding you need the returned data in. It is latin1 by default - so, you have to always change it after connect. Here is a link to the article (in russian) which describes the matter, I believe http://phpfaq.ru/charset